# How to replace a value in a tablib Dataset?

Tags: python, replace

I'm using the [`tablib`](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/) library and want to replace all entries with a certain value with another value. This operation does not seem to be supported on the `Dataset` object. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to call Python's string `replace` method on the `Dataset` exported as string and then load the string back into a new `Dataset`. To load the string back in, it needs to be saved as an in-memory stream. Using more advanced string replacement techniques like Regular expressions should be possible.

Here is an example:

```
import tablib
import io

# Creating an example dataset.
data = tablib.Dataset()
data.headers = ('first_name', 'last_name')
data.append(('John', 'Adams'))
data.append(('George', 'Washington'))
print(data.csv)
# Calling replace() on the formatted string and store it in a stream.
stream = io.StringIO(data.csv
                     .replace('George', 'Donald')
                     .replace('Washington', 'Trump'))
new_data = tablib.Dataset().load(stream.read(), format='csv')
print(new_data.csv)
```

Though the solution seems a bit "hacky" and the example is frivolous, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tags to create a subset, or use a second, intermediate dataset.
`.height` gives you the number of rows, `.lpop()` returns and removes the first row as a tuple, `.append()` adds the row back and `.stack()` merges the two datasets together. You can run tests or code normally against the extracted tuple.

```
import tablib

data = tablib.Dataset()
data.headers = ('first_name', 'last_name')
data2 = tablib.Dataset()
data2.headers = ('first_name', 'last_name')

data.append(('John', 'Adams'))
data.append(('George', 'Washington')) 

for x in range(0, data.height):
    col1, col2 = data.lpop()
    if col2 == 'Adams':
        col2 = "Eves"
    data2.append((col1, col2))
data = data.stack(data2)
```

This approach sticks with tablib and avoids having to load a second import.

Answer (score 0):

A less flexible but shorter solution:
You can overwrite entire columns using `dataset.append_col` and a function that returns the values you would like to set the entries to:

```
import tablib
data = tablib.Dataset(headers=["A","B"])

data.append((1, 2))
data.append((3, 4)) 

data.append_col(col=lambda x: 42, header = "A")
```

This will generate a new column "A" with all values set to 42.
If you run
del data["A"]
afterwards, the "old" A-column will be deleted, which will turn the whole thing into a "replace"-operation. If you need to maintain the order of the columns, you could also use `insert_col` instead, requiring a bit more caution with indices, which you don't need to hassle with if order is irrelevant.

You can provide any single-argument-single-result function for col which gives you a lot of flexibility to do whatever you want.
The only caveat here is, that the function argument is assumed to be a row, so if you want to compute the new value based on the old value, you'll need to extract the value from the corresponding row first.